# How to compare pandas date column with hardcoded date

Tags: python, pandas

This is my code:

```
print (df.loc[df.DATE == '2016-02-05'])
```

I am trying to compare this date with date of pandas. It returns empty dataframe. What should I do ?

Edit: Original dataframe:

[image]

Comment: Can you show your dataframe?

Comment: It seems there is no date, also test if working `print (df.loc[df.DATE == '2016-01-01'])`

Comment: That returned an empty dataframe

Comment: what is the type of `df.DATE`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to convert the string to a datetime object as well.

```
print(df)

datetime_str = '2015/02/04'
print("({}){}".format(type(datetime_str), datetime_str))

datetime_object = datetime.strptime(datetime_str, '%Y/%m/%d')
print("({}){}".format(type(datetime_object), datetime_object))

value = df.loc[df.DATE == datetime_object]
print("value =", value)
```

OUTPUT:

```
   year  month  day       DATE
0  2015      2    4 2015-02-04
1  2016      3    5 2016-03-05

(<class 'str'>)2015/02/04

(<class 'datetime.datetime'>)2015-02-04 00:00:00

value =    year  month  day       DATE
        0  2015  2      4         2015-02-04
```

Answer (score 1):

Just convert your string to datetime (I suppose that you dataframe also contains datetimes, rather than strings) and do the comparison you wanted to do:

```
from datetime import datetime

if __name__ == "__main__":
    t = datetime.strptime('2016-02-05', '%Y-%m-%d')
    print(t)
```

Hope the answer will help, feel free to ask questions.

If your DATE df column is not datetimes, but just strings, convert them to datetimes the same way.